# How to When/thenReturn a method of a non-attribute of a class

Tags: java, mockito

I have a method in a class as follows:

```
class Foo{

    public void foo(){
       Bar bar = new Bar();

       String barResult = bar.something();
       //code to test
    }

}
```

Note that `bar` is not an attribute of `Foo` class. I need to write a test case for `foo()` and I need a way to mock `bar.something()`.

E.g: `when(bar.something()).thenReturn('myresult');`

But it is not possible since `bar` is not accessible from the test class. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Thanks @OrangeDog I guess the solution recommended in it is to make `bar` an attribute of the class.

Comment: No, the solution (without changing the code) is to mock the constructor

Comment: It needs powermockito, which I cannot use